# Programmatically inserted Button style not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin, button, fragment

I have a problem with the style of programmatically inserted Button. I've searched many things on forums but nothing was helpful to me...

In the theme.xml file below, I have a button who work well when I set the style in the xml code of a fragment.

```
<style name="LargeMarginButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">70dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">250dp</item>
</style>
```

When i try to add buttons programmatically, `layout_margin`, `layout_height` and `layout_width` doesn't work at all, when i display the margins in logs it returns 0 for all of them.

```
class TreatmentsPresentationFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentTreatmentsPresentationBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var mainActivity: MainActivity

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentTreatmentsPresentationBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        loadButtons()

        mainActivity = activity as MainActivity
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun loadButtons() {
        val treatmentVideos = db.getVideos(false)
        
        // insert buttons in the fragment
        for (video in treatmentVideos) {
                
            // create a button with style
            val buttonContext = ContextThemeWrapper(requireContext(), R.style.LargeMarginButton)
            val button = MaterialButton(buttonContext, null)
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that all the `layout_*` elements are ignored..

Can somebody who had the same problem, or someone who can see what i've done wrong can help me please ?

Thanks.

**Edited 2021-04-13**
Thanks to [Ben P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8298909/ben-p), I understand how it works and I'm using a recycler view with an adapter based on my button view to make it work perfectly.

Comment: All `layout_` attributes are actually attributes of the `View`'s `LayoutParams`. Which type of LayoutParams (e.g., `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` vs `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`) depends on the parent ViewGroup you add your view to.

Comment: Ok, but i didn't understand why it works when i put my buttons in the xml, and why it didn't when i put my buttons programmatically

Comment: When you inflate from xml, the LayoutInflater takes care of creating `LayoutParams` objects based on `layout_` attributes. When you just instantiate a view in code, the larger context for the LayoutInflater isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added your MaterialsButtons to any ViewGroup such as LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.
Inside of `for`, add them like this:

```
private fun loadButtons() {
        val treatmentVideos = db.getVideos(false)
        
        // insert buttons in the fragment
        for (video in treatmentVideos) {
                
            // create a button with style
            val buttonContext = ContextThemeWrapper(requireContext(), R.style.LargeMarginButton)
            val button = MaterialButton(buttonContext)

            //Adding button to LienarLayout
            binding.your_linear_layout.addView(button)
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to setting LayoutParams to your button via `addView(View child, LayoutParams params)`. Depends on what ViewGroup you want your button to be added

Comment: Sorry i removed this part cause my code was a little bit long if i had let this part of my code, but i add 3 buttons in a row, and my rows in a tablelayout

That's not the problem because if i didn't have add the buttons to a view, they would not display